# создание размерной таблицы товаров Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Требуется создать таблицу размеров товара вида:
[image: Таблица размеров товара]

Делаю магазин на Django. В магазине есть категории: Обувь, рубашки, трусы, итд.
Для каждой категории существуют свои параметры размеров: для обуви - длина стопы, для рубашек - объем груди, объем талии, длина рукава, для штанов - объем бедра и объем талии. 
Следовательно в модели категории нужно каким-то образом организовать ввод необходимых размерных параметров для товара, а в модели товара заполнять эти данные и выводить на страницу товара в таблице как на рисунке.
Как правильно организовать модели?

Answer (score 0):

Такая модель данных называется [Entity–Attribute–Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). Чтобы не изобретать велосипед, попробуйте применить [django-eav](https://github.com/mvpdev/django-eav) в своём проекте.

Comment: А как правильно описать модели для таблицы размеров? Пробовал EAV - в итоге получаю для товара набор не связанных друг с другом параметов - значений. Например:
Товар Рубашка:
длина рукава - 50см.
объем талии - 50см.
объем груди - 50см.
А вот именно полноценная таблица не выходит никак